# How to pass parameter values in formula field hyperlink

Tags: configuration

I am trying to pass parameters in hyperlink url of formula field, but I am getting field names instead of it's values.

```
HYPERLINK("https://testwebsite.com/v2/search/{!Case__r.Product__c}?jt=1&jv={!CustomObject__r.C_ID__c}", "Website Link")
```

Please let me know how to pass Case__r.Product__c and CustomObject__r.C_ID__c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using something like this:

```
HYPERLINK("https://testwebsite.com/v2/search/" & variable1 & "?jt=1&jv=" & variable2, "Website Link")
```

The `&` character is used to concatenate String. You can replace variable1 and variable2 with your variables. You don't need to write their values by hand, you can use the Advanced Formula and click the Insert Field. From there you can browse your custom object's fields and it's related object's fields.

Comment: Thanks Charis. It worked great.